# sb.AppendLine Keeps Writing False Instead of Code

Tags: batch-file

I have a form that is supposed to create batch file when you click the submit button.  The Batch will Elevate UAC Prompt To Allow User To Use As Administrator.. But The Issue I'm Having with sb.AppendLine("    ""%temp%\getadmin.vbs""") in my code.  It keeps putting in FALSE where "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" is supposed to be in my batch file.  Please Help!  haha I don't know what I'm doing wrong

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder

    sb.AppendLine("@echo off")
    sb.AppendLine("")
    sb.AppendLine(":: BatchGotAdmin")
    sb.AppendLine(":-------------------------------------")
    sb.AppendLine("REM  --> Check for permissions")
    sb.AppendLine(">nul 2>&1 ""%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe"" ""%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system""")
    sb.AppendLine("")
    sb.AppendLine("REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.")
    sb.AppendLine("if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (")
    sb.AppendLine("   echo Requesting administrative privileges...")
    sb.AppendLine("    goto UACPrompt")
    sb.AppendLine(") else ( goto gotAdmin )")
    sb.AppendLine(":UACPrompt")
    sb.AppendLine("    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^(""Shell.Application""^) > ""%temp%\getadmin.vbs""")
    sb.AppendLine("    set params = %*:" = """")
    sb.AppendLine("    echo UAC.ShellExecute ""cmd.exe"", ""/c %~s0 %params%"", """", ""runas"", 1 >> ""%temp%\getadmin.vbs""")
    sb.AppendLine("    ""%temp%\getadmin.vbs""")
    sb.AppendLine("    del ""%temp%\getadmin.vbs""")
    sb.AppendLine("    exit /B")
    sb.AppendLine("")
    sb.AppendLine(":gotAdmin")
    sb.AppendLine("    pushd ""%CD%""")
    sb.AppendLine("    CD /D ""%~dp0""")
    sb.AppendLine(":--------------------------------------")
    sb.AppendLine("pause")

    IO.File.WriteAllText(Environ("SystemDrive") + "\fileName.bat", sb.ToString())

    Process.Start(Environ("SystemDrive") + "\fileName.bat")

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Think about `sb.AppendLine("    set params = %*:" = """")`.

Answer (score 0):

I changed sb.AppendLine(" set params = %*:" = """") to sb.AppendLine("set params = %*:""="""" ") and it worked. I can't believe that it was something that simple. The Code must've just grown together. Thank you so much for the help :)  I posted the updated code just in case someone may want to use it in the future.

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder

    sb.AppendLine("@echo off")
    sb.AppendLine("")
    sb.AppendLine(":: BatchGotAdmin")
    sb.AppendLine(":-------------------------------------")
    sb.AppendLine("REM  --> Check for permissions")
    sb.AppendLine(">nul 2>&1 ""%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe"" ""%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system""")
    sb.AppendLine("")
    sb.AppendLine("REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.")
    sb.AppendLine("if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (")
    sb.AppendLine("   echo Requesting administrative privileges...")
    sb.AppendLine("    goto UACPrompt")
    sb.AppendLine(") else ( goto gotAdmin )")
    sb.AppendLine(":UACPrompt")
    sb.AppendLine("    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^(""Shell.Application""^) > ""%temp%\getadmin.vbs""")
    sb.AppendLine("set params = %*:""="""" ")
    sb.AppendLine("    echo UAC.ShellExecute ""cmd.exe"", ""/c %~s0 %params%"", """", ""runas"", 1 >> ""%temp%\getadmin.vbs""")
    sb.AppendLine("""%temp%\getadmin.vbs"" ")
    sb.AppendLine("    del ""%temp%\getadmin.vbs""")
    sb.AppendLine("    exit /B")
    sb.AppendLine("")
    sb.AppendLine(":gotAdmin")
    sb.AppendLine("    pushd ""%CD%""")
    sb.AppendLine("    CD /D ""%~dp0""")
    sb.AppendLine(":--------------------------------------")
    sb.AppendLine("pause")

    IO.File.WriteAllText(Environ("SystemDrive") + "\fileName.bat", sb.ToString())



End Sub
End Class
```